# Re-configuration of community bot?

Tags: feature-request

The posting [How to add a background image to a tabular?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618893/110998) states quite clearly the problem, from the outset (no edits). Nevertheless, the community bot feels the necessity to comment:

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to
> highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard
> to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is there a way to tune the bot to react more sensibly?

Comment: The comment was issued by a real life user during review (you'll find a link in the timeline). You would need to tune the user's behaviour and not the one of the bot. Can this be done by a software update, or do they need a new firmware? :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the explanation. Tuning users is probably out of question ... Where do I find the timeline? Seems to be a corner of TeX.SX I haven't been yet.

Comment: For the timeline, click on the little clock icon https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYUM2.png , there you should see an entry for the first question review. The "Share feedback" comment means that the reviewer choose one of the pre-defined comments which them gets published under the name of the community bot

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, found.

Comment: Have fun in this new rabbit hole :) You can watch all kinds of funny stuff happening, e.g. users who first vote to close a post, then a couple of hours later the same user votes to reopen the same post without any new comments or edits which would have clarified it. Maybe replacing the users with bots would be better :)